# The Dipl.-Ing. title outside of Germany

Tags: title, qualification, germany

I am aware that in Germany if you get an equivalent of a British master's degree in engineering you get the title **Dipl.-Ing.**.

I am also aware that in Germany that tends to precede the name, in much the same way as somebody in the UK with a PhD gets to call themselves Dr. Jones instead of plain old Mr. Is it acceptable to change this order from

*Dipl.-Ing. Johann Schmitt*

to

*Johann Schmitt Dipl.-Ing.*

**Edited to answer questions:**

We use a third party database for HR purposes. It is old and inflexible and does not currently support qualifications that go before the name. The Title field (Prof, Dr., Mr, etc.) is not free text and will not currently accept the German title. We are trying to decide whether it is acceptable for the German title to go at the end or whether it'd be enough of an excuse to reach into our pockets for a new HR database.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about German Language use not really specific to navigating the workplace.

Comment: I wasn't sure which forum to put it on. I started writing it in the German language forum but decided it wasn't so much about language as professional etiquette.

Comment: I can't remember seeing anyone use anything except "Dr." in front of their name. All lesser degrees are usually omitted.

Comment: @Juha Untinen I see titles under "Dr." everyday, at least in Austria ;)

Comment: Don´t really understand the offtopic reason, but in Austria there is the Dipl.Ing. too and it is *illegal* to put it after the name.

Comment: @deviantfan - its illegal, to put a title after the name of somebody, really?

Comment: @Ramhound: Yes, really, and it´s penalized the same way as calling yourself Dipl.Ing. without having the unversity degree, ie. if you´re no Dipl.Ing. at all (and say you are). Give me some minutes, i´ll find the exact paragraph in our law (if you´re ok with lawyer-german language)

Comment: §88.2 in the Austrian University Law, full current and legally valid text here: https://www.ris.bka.gv.at/GeltendeFassung.wxe?Abfrage=Bundesnormen&Gesetzesnummer=20002128 . I know, i know, it´s Europe :p

Comment: It doesn't really say it's illegal, it's only for very formal usage

Comment: see http://wissenschaft.bmwfw.gv.at/bmwfw/studium/academic-mobility/enic-naric-austria/faq/fuehrung-akademischer-grade/ - it says it can be used freely for private use, which an employee database would construe.

Comment: Please read your own link more carefully. And the law says nothing about "only for formal usage"

Answer (score 2):

A quick search shows that even the TU Dresden gets away with using "name lastname (Dipl.-Ing.)"

That is their default template for the profiles on their webpage.

I think you don't need to change the form.

http://tu-dresden.de/die_tu_dresden/zentrale_einrichtungen/graduiertenakademie/mitglied_profil

Comment: Seconded, I saw the usag <Name>, Dipl. Ing. more often than the other way around.